# Jenkin's automated builds throws an error

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, jenkins, msbuild

I have a VS solution with projects targeting .Net 3.5 and .Net 4.5. When I build the solution on my computer it builds fine, but when I try to build using Jenkins for automated build, I get the following error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.CSharp.targets(132,4): error MSB4067: The element  beneath element  is unrecognised.
>   Build step 'Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild' marked build as failure
>   Finished: FAILURE

Does anything need to be changed for MS Build to work with Jenkins targeting .NET 3.5?

Comment: Are you using the MSBuild plugin? can you post a screenshot of the build step?

Answer (score 0):

Try use key /p:TargetFrameworkVersion="v3.5"

MSbuild path: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass the /ToolsVersion:3.5 parameter to MSBuild.

You can do this in each MSBuild build step of your project, or you can set it as a default parameter in the Manage Jenkins > Configure System > MSBuild.  Here, you can maintain specific versions of MSBuild, as well.

Comment: I've also found that setting the /p:VisualStudioVersion= parameter will work under certain circumstances.  Passing 12.0, 10.0 or the necessary version.